# org-mode regexp variables, literals missing

Tags: org-mode

I am doing code study of org-mode. And in most places, `org-mode` uses regexps defined in org.el. Like, `org-todo-line-regexp`, `org-not-done-regexp`,`org-deadline-regexp`,`org-scheduled-regexp` and `org-mode` has lot more regexp variables.

What surprises me is that, most of these regexps are `defvar`-ed with their start time values as `nil`.

where to find the regex literals for these variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should learn to use `rgrep`.
It looks like regexps are set in `org-set-regexps-and-options`.

Comment: Could you explain how rgrep pertains to your answer?

Comment: @user2699, just point at `org-todo-line-regexp` and call `rgrep`. You'll find all references to it in the source.